# What is the best way to build a json API using Play Framework and Morphia?

Tags: playframework, morphia

- Play 1.2.4
- Morphia 1.2.6a
- ExtJs 4.x

The framework appears to support creating a model, adding validation, and passing it as a parameter or a result with ease. I have tried that for a few days and have yet to see an update passing an object that work. But, what have you done with Play?

Let's assume a simple example of a contact with a name and phone number, maybe an address. Methods are basic create, update, delete, and select. The create and update calls seem to be the challenging ones here.

Is it manually mapping Json elements to object getters/setters. That seems laborious.

Can the framework auto-parse objects like App.Save(Contact) or something like that? Is there an example somewhere?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Not quite sure what your mean. simplest way for mapping is: client use Gson to send a String , action receive a String and convert it to model use Gson as well.

Comment: If the storage class includes extra internal fields that you do not want to share and certainly do not want external updates on, a direct fetch-parse-convert is not a good plan. My question back in May 2012 (yup, this is an old question) was looking for an efficient and low code way to filter the wire data structure from the storage data structure. In the end I ended up with somewhat of a get/set map which was not what I was hoping for.

Comment: Re-reading my original question, I was also looking for a low-coding way to map the incoming string to a class. There were examples of putting the object on the method parameter list and have the string parsed and auto-populate the object before calling the method, but that never seemed to work.